# Destructured parameter properties in constructor

Tags: typescript

Typescript allows parameter properties

```
class ParameterProperty {
  constructor(private member: number) {}
}
```

The above creates a class with private member `member`, the constructor sets `this.member` to the  first argument of the constructor.

But there is no equivalent for 'named parameters' via destructuring.

```
interface DestructedOptions {
  prefix: string;
  suffix: string;
}

class Destructed {
  constructor({private prefix, private suffix}: DestructedOptions) {}
}
```

The above doesn't work, you have to do something  like this:

```
class Destructed {
  private prefix: string
  private suffix: string
  constructor({prefix, suffix}: DestructedOptions) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.suffix = suffix;
  }
}
```

which is really verbose and requires updates to three places when adding a new property to `DestructuredOptions`. I tried something similar, using mapped properties

```
class Destructed {
  private [P in keyof DestructedOptions]: T[DestructedOptions];
  constructor(opts: DestructedOptions) {
    Object.assign(this, opts)
  }
}
```

Only to find out that mapped properties can only be used in Types, not interfaces or classes. I don't like this option anyway since it copies everything from opts, I would really want something like this:

```
class Destructed {
  constructor(opts: DestructedOptions) {
    for (let key in keyof DestructedOptions) {
      this[key] = opts[key];
    }
  }
}
```

But of course typescript doesn't let you get runtime values from Types.

Comment: It doesn't solve your problem, but you should also use the ```implements``` keyword to create an explicit abstraction of the relationship between the class Destructed and the interface DestructedOptions

Comment: There is no obvious, easy, direct solution to your problem. If you want a property to be declared, you have to declare it.

Comment: look my answer with links  after some days of research:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343165/typescript-destructuring-object-literal-in-construct-of-the-class-default-prope/44367990#44367990

Answer (score 17):

What about:

```
class Destructed {
    private prefix: string;
    private suffix: string;

    constructor(opts: DestructedOptions) {
        Object.assign(this, opts);
    }
}
```

Also, there's an open issue on this: [Combining destructuring with parameter properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326)

---

#### Edit

If you want to avoid re-writing the properties in the class then you'll need to make the members public, when that's the case then the solution is as shown in the issue I linked to:

```
class Destructed {
    constructor(opts: DestructedOptions) {
        Object.assign(this, opts);
    }
}

interface Destructed extends DestructedOptions { }

let destructed = new Destructed({ prefix: "prefix", suffix: "suffix" });
console.log(destructed.prefix);
console.log(destructed.suffix);
console.log(destructed.DoesntExist); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20DestructedOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prefix%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20suffix%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Destructed%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(opts%3A%20DestructedOptions)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20opts)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Destructed%20extends%20DestructedOptions%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20destructed%20%3D%20new%20Destructed(%7B%20prefix%3A%20%22prefix%22%2C%20suffix%3A%20%22suffix%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(destructed.prefix)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(destructed.suffix)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(destructed.DoesntExist)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

Comment: But his whole point is that he wants to avoid having to declare the properties individually.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah, that's the price to pay for having the members private. But it does save the hassle of assigning each value to the members.

Comment: @nitzan-tomer, but with the drawback of writing _everything_ from `opts` into `this`.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: This means that any reference to `destructed.prefix` will fail, and he will have to abandon type checking and write `destructed["prefix"]`, which is not a very good solution.

Comment: @torazaburo Why does it mean that? Check my revised answer again, I added more code and a link to playground. It works just fine.

Comment: I'm trying this version together with default values from an object, and I struggle with this issue:
Object.assign(this, defaults, opts);
will cause the override of defaults object. Even when trying to make a copy of it (defaultsCopy) - still it's being overiden. Any idea?

Comment: @jizanthapus i'm not sure what you mean. sounds like you should write your own question

Answer (score 5):

In ECMAScript, [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) results in variables in variables (not properties than properties) receiving the component values.

There has been a TypeScript feature request/suggestion for [combining destructuring with parameter properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326) open since October of 2015.   That would probably be the most effective place to track the status of whatyou want.

Answer (score 2):

There's no obvious, direct way to do what you want. Consider holding `options` in your class instead of individual properties, as in

```
interface DestructedOptions {
  prefix: string;
  suffix: string;
}

class Destructed {
  constructor(public options: DestructedOptions) {}
}

<!-- in template -->
Prefix is {{options.prefix}}!!
```