# typescript destructuring object literal in construct of the class, default properties does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to use default values for destructuring object literal, but I don't get the default values, just 'undefined'. What is the right way?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
 // constructor( {id = 3, name = 'defaulthero'} = {}) {
  constructor( {id  , name }: {id?: number, name?: string } = { id:3, name: 'defaulthero'} ) {
    console.log( id, name);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>Hero {{hero3.id}} {{hero3.name}}</h2>`,
})
export class AppComponent    {
  title = 'Tour of Heros';
  public hero3: Hero;


  ngOnInit() {

    //this.hero3  = new Hero (  ) ;  // work
    //this.hero3  = new Hero (  {} ) ; // does not work
    this.hero3  = new Hero ( {id: 0} ) ;  // does not work, default value 'defaulthero' not assign, just i get 'undefined'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found two alternatives solutions inspired in:

1) Solution class Hero:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-checking-for-destructuring-object-literal

2) Solution class Hero2: section "Optional Properties"
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

interface HeroInterface { 
  // you need add ? for each variable (Optional Properties)
  id?: number;
  name?: string;

}

// Class using solution 1
class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  //without interface: constructor({id= 3, name= 'defaulthero'}: {id?: number, name?: string } = {}) {
  constructor({id= 4, name= 'Spiderman'}: HeroInterface = {}) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

}

// Class solution 2 ,using short way of assign property on constructor()
class Hero2 {
  constructor(public config: HeroInterface = {}) { // short way to assign config like this.config = config; 

    if (!config.id) this.config.id =10;
    if (!config.name) this.config.name = 'SuperMan';
  }

}


@Component ( {
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `hero1: id: {{hero.id}} name: {{hero.name}} 
            <br/>hero2: id: {{hero2.config.id}} name: {{hero2.config.name}}
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hero: Hero ;
  hero2: Hero2 ;
  ngOnInit () {

    // SOLUTION 1:  
    // this.hero = new Hero ();
    this.hero = new Hero ( { id:9 });

    // SOLUTION 2:
    this.hero2 = new Hero2 ( ); // Works with default values
    //this.hero2 = new Hero2 ( { id: 20} ); // Works with default name value
    //this.hero2 =  new Hero2 ( { id: 20, name: 'Asterix'}); // send all values, don't need use default values
    //this.hero2 = new Hero2 ( { id:19 , name: 'Asterix', weight:90}); // Error, 'weight' does not exist in type 'HeroInterface'
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer is much more misleading others to creat a extra interface just in order to create an instance of existing class. basically you should use `constructor(id: string = '3', name= 'Spiderman')` or the way I provided with just one line code.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't assign default value for `object fields`, typescript will treat it as a normal parameter(type of object) like below:

```
constructor(obj: any = {id:3, name: 'defaulthero'})
```

- when creating a new instance of `hero` by `new Hero()`, there will be no parameter for `constructor`, so the default `{id:3, name: 'defaulthero'}` will be used.
- when creating a new instance of `hero` by `new Hero({})`, there will be one parameter which is an object with no fields and it will be used as the income parameter and take the place of default `{id:3, name: 'defaulthero'}`.(the same as `new Hero ( {id: 0} )`)

---

as you have one commented line at your code block, you can assign default value for fields of object parameters with the below changes:

```
constructor({id=3, name='defaulthero'}: {id?: number, name?: string } = {}) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
}
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FM0QqyKmbzN0CAoEaIju?p=preview)**

Comment: warning: all variables must to have  "?",  when typescript find an error with angular hero tutorial , you see the last ok compilation, then you think it's working , but no, error with typescript is not compiling really; better to break and launch npm start, to be sure.

Comment: sorry, but i've found a best two solutions, look at my own answer

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended, you are setting a default value for *the object* and then it gets destructed. If you replace that object with your own, only values from it will populate your arguments. However, here is a way to archive the behaviour you want, instead of setting default value to the object:

```
  constructor({id, name }: {id?: number, name?: string } = {id:3, name: 'defaulthero'}) {
    console.log( id, name);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
```

Do it for each argument:

```
  constructor({id = 3, name = 'defaulthero'}: {id?: number, name?: string }  = {}) {
    console.log( id, name);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
```