# Is there an elegant way of passing an object of parameters into a function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following method which takes a set of data and creates a new instance of a model from it. The `reportTemplateData` comes in as an object which I destructure in order to pass in as a list of properties to the class constructor.

Whilst this works, I feel like it could be done far more efficiently. Is there a more elegant way to do this in a line or so?

```
addReportTemplate(reportTemplateData) {
  const {
    id,
    pageId,
    profileTemplateId,
    userId,
    name,
    description,
    createdAt,
    updatedAt,
    deletedAt,
    createdBy,
    updatedBy,
    deletedBy,
    reportTemplateColumns,
  } = reportTemplateData;
  const newReportTemplate = new ReportTemplate(
    id,
    pageId,
    profileTemplateId,
    userId,
    name,
    description,
    createdAt,
    updatedAt,
    deletedAt,
    createdBy,
    updatedBy,
    deletedBy,
    reportTemplateColumns,
  );
  this.reportTemplates.push(reportTemplates);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Worth noting that if you go for the `const newReportTemplate = new ReportTemplate({...reportTemplateData})` solution, you must match your data properties precisely to your class constructor parameters. This was an issue for me where the data was coming in in snake_case whereas my Javascript model was looking for camelCase.

Comment: In the last line: `this.reportTemplates.push(reportTemplates);`, where does `reportTemplates` come from?

Comment: Can you not modify `ReportTemplate`? For example redefine it to deconstruct incoming objects, `function ReportTemplate({id, profileTemplateId /*etc*/})` then just pass the object directily, `new ReportTemplate(reportTemplateData)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that only the properties you want to pass are in that object.

```
addReportTemplate(reportTemplateData) {
  const newReportTemplate = new ReportTemplate({ ...reportTemplateData });
  this.reportTemplates.push(reportTemplates);
}
```

If there are a few properties you want to exclude, destructure them.

```
addReportTemplate(reportTemplateData) {
  const { 
      excluded1,
      excluded2,
      ...properties,
   } = reportTemplateData;
  const newReportTemplate = new ReportTemplate({ ...properties });
  this.reportTemplates.push(reportTemplates);
}
```

Both of these approaches require a change in ReportTemplate class where the constructor takes an object as parameter.
See two examples of how this approach would work in [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBOzRe).

Comment: Would be great if this works, but I tried and it fails in [my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yh7rn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: I haven't touched TS myself before but is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vm2c6y) something that would work for you? Got that solution using help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838329/7626876)

Comment: That would change the ctor to get a single object, instead of using individual parameters (what I don't want). But due to the fact that TS is a superset of JS I thought that everything that works in JS should also work in TS.

Comment: If you could provide a working example in JS (e.g. on stackblitz, jsfiddle, whatever) where the class has individual parameters in its ctor and you push in an object (just like you presented above). That would be great.

Comment: It does not work this way, I will update my answer. There are 2 options to make it work like this see [pin](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBOzRe)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, what is not possible. You can only replace your multiple arguments against a single object arguments holding all the parameters. But there doesn't exist any unfolding of objects to parameter lists of constructors or functions. :-(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `ReportTemplate` can take a single object as an input parameter instead of having a plenty of arguments.

If it's not possible, you can simplify it a bit, having destructurization right in your function definition:

```
addReportTemplate({
    id,
    pageId,
    profileTemplateId,
    userId,
    name,
    description,
    createdAt,
    updatedAt,
    deletedAt,
    createdBy,
    updatedBy,
    deletedBy,
    reportTemplateColumns,
  }) {
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is my usual method but I'm using Flow for this project and it has made things more complicated than usual.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of property names instead, extract the properties from the argument, and call `ReportTemplate` with an object with those properties. You can use `reduce` to transform the array of property names into an object with those properties. For example:

```js
function addReportTemplate(reportTemplateData) {
  const propNames = ['id', 'pageId', 'userId'];
  const templateArg = propNames.reduce((a, propName) => {
    a[propName] = reportTemplateData[propName];
    return a;
  }, {});
  console.log(templateArg);
}
addReportTemplate({
  id: 'id!',
  pageId: 'pageId!',
  userId: 'userId!',
  someOtherProp: 'someOtherProp'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of destructuring `reportTemplateData` and passing individual fields from it, you could simply use spread operator `...` and pass as object:

```
addReportTemplate(reportTemplateData) {
    const newReportTemplate = new ReportTemplate({...reportTemplateData});
    this.reportTemplates.push(newReportTemplate);
}
```

And finally in `ReportTemplate` receive the params as a single object and in there you could destructure required fields.

Comment: Would be great if this works, but I tried and it fails in [my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yh7rn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

If `ReportTemplate` must be given only specific parameters and `addReportTemplate` can be given any parameter, you can use this variant:

```
addReportTemplate(reportTemplateData) {
  const newReportTemplates = {};

  for (const param in [
    'id',
    'pageId',
    'profileTemplateId',
    'userId',
    'name',
    'description',
    'createdAt',
    'updatedAt',
    'deletedAt',
    'createdBy',
    'updatedBy',
    'deletedBy',
    'reportTemplateColumns',
  ]) {
    newReportTemplates[param] = reportTemplateData[param];
  }

  this.reportTemplates.push(newReportTemplates);
}
```

Otherwise the other answers are great.