# Typescript: Shortening Simple Class Declaration

Tags: typescript, class, design-patterns, interface, dry

I have a TS code pattern that I find very useful but it is extremely not **DRY**. Any ideas how to fix it?

I like to "link" together a TS `interface` with a `class` declaration. In this way I have the advantage of some simple typed data-structure with inheritance, AND I can easily do type checks at runtime with a `instanceof` operator (that allows me to avoid [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), which I find unsafe).

**For an example see the code below, where I have a class `Doctor` which extends a base class `Person`**

```js
interface PersonInterface {
  id: number
  name: string
  surname: string
}
class Person implements PersonInterface {
  id: number
  name: string
  surname: string

  constructor(arg: PersonInterface) {
    this.id = arg.id
    this.name = arg.name
    this.surname = arg.surname
  }
}

interface DoctorInterface extends PersonInterface {
  degree: string
  salary: number
}
class Doctor extends Person implements DoctorInterface {
  degree: string
  salary: number

  constructor(arg: DoctorInterface) {
    super(arg)
    this.degree = arg.degree
    this.salary = arg.salary
  }
}

const doc = new Doctor({
  id: 111,
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Johnson',
  degree: 'PHD',
  salary: 100000,
})

console.log(doc instanceof Person) // true
console.log(doc instanceof Doctor) // true
```

Everything works, the type check is easy and my IntelliSense is happy. All great. But as you can see I am repeating myself 3 times for each class. One time to declare the `interface`, another to implement it in the `class` and a final one to apply the `constructor`.

Isn't there a more coincise way? In a big project this becomes horrible to look at.

**IMPORTANT**
I do not need to have methods in my classes. They are used only to rapresent data, not behaviour (in fact I am using them to populate a *vuex* store)

Comment: How critical is it for the objects to be passed a dictionary? You might be able to use [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) in some cases to cut down the duplication.

Comment: I tried that in different ways but I haven't find a way that works well with inheritance... TS will complain a lot about interfaces not being correctly implemented or properties not being correctly initialised. In some case it seams to work but when I instantiate the class all is property are not known to TS and accessing them gives more errors.

Comment: There's a way to do it with objects [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838329/1426891) if you're comfortable using `Object.assign` and potentially copying all enumerable properties, not just the named three or however many. That answer also links to [issue #5326](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326), which is what you want but isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no magic syntax to make this nicer.

But it is worth noting that a class can be used as an interface:

```
class Person {
  id: number
  name: string
  surname: string

  constructor(arg: Person) {
    this.id = arg.id
    this.name = arg.name
    this.surname = arg.surname
  }
}

// works
const personData: Person = { id: 123, name: 'Al', surname: 'Bundy' }
const person: Person = new Person(personData)
```

You may think that is a bit odd, but the plain object and the instance of `Person` both have the exact same public interface, so they are considered compatible.

---

> **IMPORTANT** I do not need to have methods in my classes. They are used only to rapresent data, not behaviour (in fact I am using them to populate a vuex store)

So why are you using classes at all? Then there's no need. A plain object that conforms to that interface is more or less indistinguishable from the instance of a class that implements that interface, so you can save a lot of boilerplate with just:

```
interface Person {
  id: number
  name: string
  surname: string
}

const person: Person = { id: 123, name: 'Al', surname: 'Bundy' }
```

Comment: Hey Wayne, yours is probably the good answer, but I will still wait a moment in case there is some magician with some obscure special syntax for what I am looking for.

Already using classes as interfaces is making things better. Thanks.

I still want to use classes instead of a plain object, so I can have `instanceof` as a type [narrowing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing). I found it readable and robust... better than [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: Another option is [discriminated unions](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-case-for-discriminated-union-types-with-typescript#introducing-discriminated-unions). Just give all your interfaces a common type field and `if (myData.type === 'person') { ... }`

Comment: That's a great suggestion! It does cover my needs. Thank you.